# Magento2.3 - How to create dropdown for states from italy country?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am new in `Magento2.3`. I want to create a Drop down for states for Italy country.

In `Magento1` we have used below code:

```
INSERT INTO  `magento1.6`.`directory_country_region` (
`region_id` ,
`country_id` ,
`code` ,
`default_name`
)
VALUES (
'0',  'IN',  'IN-DL',  'New Delhi'
);
```

What is the code in Magento2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento 2 directory_country_region table is the same with magento 1. You can use same SQL to add Italy states:

```
INSERT INTO  `magento2.3`.`directory_country_region` (
`country_id` ,
`code`,
`default_name`
)
VALUES ('IT',  'Rome',  'Rome');
```

We don't  need region_id because it is auto increasement.

Please note that same state name can be added multiple times so if you run insert query more than once, you will end up with something like this:

[image]

If this happens, you can go to your database and remove the dupplicated entries.

Comment: thank you this works from me.. but do you have list of all provisions of italy country

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not resident of EU so I don't know very much about it.  But I think you can use this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provinces_of_Italy#List_of_provinces

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 you can enable state options in backend of your shop 
login in Magento backend and go to tab

Store->General->General you will see state options you have to enable that for Italy and clear cache

[image]

```
bin/magento clear:cache
```

Comment: yes its correct but i want to add these using schema.php how can i do that